# Why dropdown menu goes behind the javascript plugin (Google Earth) in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, google-earth-plugin

I have designed the following page using BootStrap, and a Google Earth plugin as a script to the page.

http://www.northeastern.edu/sds/web/demos/coldextremes.shtml

I wonder why the right dropdown menu (Precipitation) drops behind the plugin in Chrome,Version 27.0.1453.110 m. It is working fine in Firefox and IE10

thank you for your help

Answer (score 2):

You need to use an `<iframe>` shim. This is an `<iframe>` positioned and sized to match your dropdown menu. I believe this is the only reliable way to overlay other content on top of the Earth plugin in all browsers.

Does the menu system you're using have an option to use a shim? If not, then you will need to add it yourself. A good place to start would be Brandon Aaron's [bgiframe plugin](https://github.com/brandonaaron/bgiframe).

Also, you will need to get rid of the rounded corners and drop shadows. Those won't work on top of the Earth plugin. You probably noticed that in Firefox, although the menu works, it has sharp edges at the bottom and right, and a pixelated corner. You'll have the same problem with the shim—it's purely rectangular. Luckily, flat design is "in" these days, so use it in this menu: square corners and no drop shadows.

Or, you could finesse the situation…

I recommend at least considering a different approach: Live with, and embrace, the limitations imposed by the Earth plugin. The plugin really wants its own space, so give it to it. Don't try to overlay your own content on top of it. Instead, put the "menu" next to it. This could be an accordion-style list, or some kind of tree, or there are any number of ways you could put some navigation in its own panel next to the Earth plugin. This will avoid all the issues with background iframes and browser compatibility.

Source: I worked on a large Earth-plugin-based product for the educational market, and we spent literally *months* dealing with the issues that came up as a result of wanting to overlay various kinds of menus and similar material on top of the plugin.

Comment: Thank you so much. I think I should get your advice to give it its own place! I don't want to face more problems.